# android transfert map tiles take several hours

Tags: android

I have made an application that work with offline map. For that i have a huge (200k files) amount of tile png. 
I would like to transfer them on my android device but when i start the copy paste, windows told me 8hours ! I have to transfer all those files on 13 android devices and i don't have the time to wait that long.

I have tried to transfer them in a zip but all the zip application crash when i tried to unzip them.

If you have any solution, plz give it to me.

Thanks.
Nicolas Sagon.

Comment: Unzipping should be fine, show your code and the error you get

Comment: If i try with ex explorer ("Division by zero error") if i try 7zip app no error just crash